# Understanding Docker container resource usage

Tags: nginx, docker

I have server running Ubuntu 16.04 with Docker 17.03.0-ce running an Nginx container. That server also has [ConfigServer Security & Firewall](https://configserver.com/cp/csf.html) installed. Shortly after starting the Nginx container I start receiving emails about "Excessive resource usage" with the following details:

```
Time:         Fri Mar 24 00:06:02 2017 -0400
Account:      systemd-timesync
Resource:     Process Time
Exceeded:     1820 > 1800 (seconds)
Executable:   /usr/sbin/nginx
Command Line: nginx: worker process
PID:          2302 (Parent PID:2077)
Killed:       No
```

I fully understand that I can add `exe:/usr/sbin/nginx` to csf.pignore to stop these email alerts but I would like to understand a few things first.

- Why is the "systemd-timesync" account being reported? That does not seem to have anything to do with Docker.
- Why does the host machine seem to be reporting the excessive resource usage (the extended process time) when that is something running in the container?
- Why are other docker containers not running Nginx not resulting in excessive resource usage emails?

I'm sure there are other questions but basically, why is this being reported the way it is being reported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can at least answer the first two questions:

Unlike real VMs, Docker containers are simply a collection of processes run under the host system kernel. They just have a different view on certain system resources, including their own file hierarchy, their own PID namespace and their own `/etc/passwd` file. As a result, they will still show up if you `ps aux` on the host machine.

The nginx container's `/etc/passwd` includes a user 'nginx' with UID 104 that runs the nginx worker process. However, in the host's `/etc/passwd`, UID 104 might belong to a completely different user, such as `systemd-timesync`.

As a result, if you run `ps aux | grep nginx` in the container, you might see

```
nginx        7  0.0  0.0  32152  2816 ?        S    11:20   0:00 nginx: worker process
```

while on the host, you see

```
systemd-timesync   22004  0.0  0.0  32152  2816 ?        S    13:20   0:00 nginx: worker process
```

even though both are the are the same process (also note the different PID namespaces; in containers, PIDs are counted from 1 again).

As a result, container processes will still be subject to ConfigServer's resource monitoring, but they might show up with random, or even non-existent user accounts.

As to why nginx triggers the emails and other containers don't, I can only assume that nginx is the only one of your containers that crosses ConfigServer's resource thresholds.